# Image is not been visible at the secondary CALayer

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have the code like that:

```
// 1.
UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(contentSize, false, 0);
// 2.
//UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(contentSize);
using (var g = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext()) {
      g.TranslateCTM(0, contentSize.Height);
      g.ScaleCTM(1, -1);
      DrawContent(g, contentSize);
}
img = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
// skip some stuff        
mylayer.Contents = img.CGImage;
```

If I use (1) variant I don't see any drawing. If I use (2) variant I see blurred image.
For checking image I drew it by context.DrawImage and (1) variant looks sharp.
myLayer it is CALayer that was created.
What difference between BeginImageContextWithOptions and BeginImageContext so layer don't draw image was produced first one?

**UPDATE:**

It is turned out that the problem doesn't occur in the really device (I have only 5s). But it occurs on iPhone simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem! It's due to too large image for simulator. In debug mode I make it smaller and simulator begin to show it!

Answer (score 0):

From Apple Developer Documentation

> **UIGraphicsBeginImageContext**
>
> This function is equivalent to calling the 
>   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions
>   function with the opaque parameter set to 
>   NO
>    and a scale factor of 1.0.

In other words the difference between these function calls is the value of scale factor.

```
//scale factor is 1
UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(contentSize);
```

```cs
//scale factor is 0
UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(contentSize, false, 0);
```

If you explicitly pass 0 as a scale parameter the scale factor will be set to the scale factor of device's main screen. This value can range between 1-3 depending on the device screen resolution. You can access it through `UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale`.

Comment: Sure, if I set scale=1 in calling the BeginImageContextWithOptions I get same result. But problem is not solved as I cannot use scale!=0 because I don't see image on layer.